# How to creat view with special filter?

Tags: list-view, custom-list, filter

I would like to create a default, public view on a custom list, where the users have a default filter by creators, so everyone can see only the items what are created by him/her. So the filter should be dynamic based on who is the user. (I know there is an option to make the users see only the items what are created by him/her, but there are unique fields in the list so that is not useable.)

Thanks u very much for any suggestion!

Comment: What type of column is your 'unique' field? People Picker type columns are the only ones that work with the [me] filter to allow this to happen.

Comment: Luckly looks like working well with it. The creator of the item is a Auto People Picker type. The unique field is a script generated unique item ID based on the date and the number of created item in the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the view, scroll down to Filter, show only items when..., select Created By, Is equal to, [Me] . Both the square brackets and the capital M are important.

You can use this whether or not the Created By field is checked off for display in your view, and unless you're doing something super fancy with Content Types, the Created By field is attached to every list and library element.